# determine when all cyclic shifts are distinct

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

> Prove that if $a,b$ are coprime positive integers, then for any path from $(0,0)$ to $(b,a)$ where each step involves going up or to the right one unit, then all cyclic shifts of $P$ are distinct. For instance, if $R$ denotes a right step and $U$ denotes an up step and if $a=2,b=3,$ then the cyclic shifts of $RU$ are $UR$ and $RU$.

> Prove or disprove the converse (i.e. if for any path from $(0,0)$ to $(b,a)$ where each step involves going up or to the right one unit, all cyclic shifts of $P$ are distinct, $a$ and $b$ are coprime).

I think distinct cyclic shifts can only be equal if in some sense, they're "multiples of each other." That is, if there's two repetitions of the same pattern. So if there are two distinct cyclic shifts that are identical, one should be able to prove that $a$ and $b$ have a common factor. I think one can prove that if a string has only two letters and each occurs an odd number of times, then no distinct cyclic shifts of the string are the same (distinct as in the shifts involve different indices of the string). To prove this, it would probably be useful to induct on the number of occurrences of the letter with the fewest occurrences, with the base case being one occurrence. The inductive step would involve listing a cyclic shift as $s_i s_{i+1}\cdots s_{i+n-1}$ and another as $s_j s_{j+1}\cdots s_{j+n-1}$ such that the two are equal. Here we're assuming we have a string of length n and that we're using cyclic indices (so $s_{i+n} = s_i\,\forall i$). There is some $1\leq k < n$ with $s_{i+k} = s_j = s_{j+k}$. Replacing $s_{j}$ and $s_i$ with the other character however doesn't seem to help much. But I'm stuck as to what to do next as $j+k$ might be a different index from $i$.

I think the converse might also hold, and to show it, it might be useful to prove the contrapositive. Let $d = \gcd(a,b).$ Construct a path consisting of $\frac{a}d$ R steps followed by $\frac{b}d $ U steps. Repeat this path $d > 1$ times. Then note that cyclically shifting the path by $\frac{a}d$ indices always yields the same path, because the letters representing the path are periodic with period $\frac{a+b}d$ (more formally if $D_i$ represents the ith direction of the path, then using cyclic indices, $D_{i+(a+b)/d} = D_i$).

Comment: Does $P$ stand for any path? What does $L$ stand for in $RL$ and $LR$,  when the alphabet of moves consists of $R$ and $U$? How is $RL$ a path from $(0,0)$ to $(2,3)$?

Comment: Can you name the source  of the contest, please? We have a strict policy not to discuss questions from a current contest (I think that includes questions from team selection tests).

Comment: Anyway, your method of attacking the converse is what I would do, too. So that looks good. I don't think induction $a+b$ is the right line of attack to the early part though. If for no reason other than that a cyclic shift involves the entire sequence of moves rather than some segment.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen this is a question I literally made up. It's based off a solution to a contest in that was held in 2000.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the extras.